# Weird in Header Files

Tags: c++, header, doxygen

I have lines in header files that are like:

```
public:
    //! @name Constructor / Destructor
    //@{
    //! Constructor.
        CP_AboutBox( CP_Application_Imp *inOwnerApp );
        virtual ~CP_AboutBox() throw();
    //@}

    //! @name Instance
    //@{
        static  CP_AboutBox                 *Instance();
    //@}

    //! @name Display
    //@{
        void    Display( const CP_String& inDescription = CP_String("") );
    //@}

    //! @name Setters
    //@{
```

What is all this `@name Instance` and `@name Display`?

is it Doxygen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see for example this section from the [Doxygen documentaion](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock) which explains it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's doxygen style comments. http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup